# Delete a matching pattern with sed

Tags: sed

I try to delete all occcurence of a word from my xml file. The pattern I would like to delete is something like below:

```
& lt;foo_bar&gt;300&lt;/foo_bar& gt;
```

I am not familiar with sed, but I know it's feasible using it. I tried something like :

```
sed 's^&lt[foo_bar]&gt;$g' myfile.xml
```

or

```
sed 's/^&lt[foo_bar]&gt;$//' myfile.xml
```

both failed with an error message. So could you please help me how to figure out this? OS is Solaris 10 so most likely standart version is sed installed not GNU one. Please ignore space after & sign in the expression. There is no space in actual expression.

Thanks

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: sed -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, the way you are using character classes `[foo_bar]` is wrong. `[foo_bar]` can match one of `f,o,b,a,r,_` only once. And you seem to have no attempt at matching `/`. The first expression you have lacks regex delimiters. sed will assume you are using `^` as the delimiter but then it lacks the corresponding delimiters as in `s^find^replace^g`.

This seems to work:

```
sed 's!&lt;foo_bar&gt;[^&]*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;!!g' input
```

Comment: it showed the lines containing the pattern but didn't delete them.

Comment: i think you need to copy/paste some actual input. there is something wrong with the input or something else

Comment: I created a test file including my pattern: 
cat test2.xml

&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;xyzzzadswfsdfdfgdsf 
blablabla
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;defefegewrger 
blablablabla
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;dsfdfd:w

So I run the command as you suggested:
sed 's!&lt;foo_bar&gt;[0-9]*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;!!' ./test2.xml <br>

Comment: The output is:
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;xyzzzadswfsdfdfgdsf
blablabla
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;defefegewrger
blablablabla
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;dsfdfd:w

And if I cat the file after the command, pattern is still there:

cat test2.xml
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;xyzzzadswfsdfdfgdsf
blablabla
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;defefegewrger
blablablabla
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;dsfdfd:w

I don't know if it differs but this is a test box in virtualbox and OS is Ubuntu not Solaris.

Thanks

Comment: yes this time output changed to:
sed 's!&lt;foo_bar&gt;[^&]*&lt;/foo_bar&gt;!!g' test2.xml

xyzzzadswfsdfdfgdsf 
blablabla 
defefegewrger 
blablablabla 
dsfdfd:w 

Matching pattern are removed from output as I wish, but they are still in the actual file when I cat file.

Comment: @user2103312 Redirect that to a new file using `>` in the shell.  Try your sed command followed by a `> new_file`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/&\s*lt;(foo_bar&)gt;[0-9]+&lt;\/\1\s*gt;//g' file
```

Comment: Matching patterns are removed from output but not from actual file:<br/>

 sed -r 's/&\s*lt;(foo_bar&)gt;[0-9]+&lt;\/\1\s*gt;//g' test2.xml
xyzzzadswfsdfdfgdsf <br/>
blablabla <br/>
defefegewrger <br/>
blablablabla <br/>
dsfdfd:w <br/>

user@emrubuntu:~/Desktop$ cat test2.xml <br/>
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300&lt;/foo_bar&gt;xyzzzadswfsdfdfgdsf <br/>
blablabla <br/>
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300&lt;/foo_bar&gt;defefegewrger <br/>
blablablabla <br/>
&lt;foo_bar&gt;300&lt;/foo_bar&gt;dsfdfd:w <br/>